# Return Only different values for property

Tags: powershell

im hoping someone can help me, and I hope this is an easy one.  I am looking to return a certain property for users in my AD, but only different values of that property.  I have put the command I started with below, however this command returns the property for every user, I only want it to return the different BusinessUnits one time, I dont want to see multiple entries for the same business unit.  Perhaps there is a "where option" to say where value of property is different?  I hope Im making sense, if not, go ahead and ask for any additional information.  Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

```
get-aduser -filter * -searchbase $ou -Properties businessunit | select businessunit | sort businessunit | Out-GridView
```

Thanks to malexander, Groub-Object was exactly what I needed, never used that one before!  :-)
Here is my working command

```
get-aduser -filter * -searchbase $ou -Properties businessunit | Group-Object -Property businessunit | Select Name | Sort Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the  `Group-Object` cmdlet.  I believe it will do exactly what you are asking.  I have used it to pull uniques before like so.

```
$test= @(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

$test | Group-Object | % {write-host $_.name}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works great.  One more thing, is there a way to exclude a certain businessunit from coming up?  We have some blanks, and I dont want to see blanks.  I know, I know, I keep making this harder  ;-)

Comment: Nevermind I found it, I modified my filter, my command now looks like this!  woot woot  get-aduser -filter {businessunit -like "*"} -searchbase $ou -Properties businessunit | Group-Object -Property businessunit | Select Name | Sort Name